# couchbase per user data approach

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

having a bit of trouble finding the correct way to model per user data in couchbase and sync up via couchbase mobile for user specific data.  In couchdb you have a separate database per user.  What is the best approach in couchbase ?

Comment: maybe you can make userID a prefix of his keys to achieve that kind of multi-tenancy?

Answer (score 1):

In Couchbase there is no such thing as "user data". Its generic and open for your designs.

Normally when you design your object domain model for Couchbase you would inject metadata in your key structure.

For example:
Key for Account: "**Acc**#123456789" - where prefix "Acc#" is telling about type of the key, and "123456789" adds particular address instance of this key...resulting in the unique key.
Similarly if you want to encode associated address to the account, you'd architect the following key: "Acc#123456789#**Addr**" - where postfix "#Addr" identifies type of the key for address object

Now, if you want to have user specific keys, you just simply inject user identifier into the key value (from the example above):

- key "Acc#123456789" will transform to "**usr#12345**#Acc#123456789"
- key "Acc#123456789#Addr" will transform to "**usr#12345**#Acc#123456789#Addr"

Read more on Couchbase data modeling [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.0/#modeling-documents) and [keys and metadata](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#keys-and-metadata)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your documents in that way which can able to ease the retrieve all related entity. e.g.

1. Create your documents with `user_{Guid}` consider `Guid` as your UserID
2. Make all other related document with this same `Guid` like `credential_{Guid}` so when user logged in we can have userID in session and get all information of that user.